# Different JSON deserialization settings per controller in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, system.text.json, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to set different `JsonSerializerOptions` for specific controllers. Specifically, I want to set `ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve` for those controllers only, and inherit the rest of the serializer options from some static instance.

I'm looking for a way to do this at the controller level, using `System.Text.Json` on ASP.NET Core 6.0.

I was able to do this for serialization using an Action Filter using this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56127866/2719183, but I haven't been able to find a good solution to implement this for deserialization. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/66256442/2719183, does not work for me because it requires an attribute for each parameter.

How do I override an input formatter at the controller level?

Comment: Would writing a custom converter [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to) solve your problem?

Comment: @mu88 No, I am not looking to customize the serialization itself. I am looking to set the `JsonSerializerOptions` differently for certain controllers in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Okay, I see your point... the only thing I found so far is `IControllerConfiguration` which was available in the old ASP.NET stack (full framework). Maybe you can dig into the sources and find/build something similar

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems: serialization and deserialization.

1. Serialization. This is relatively easy, you have to create action filter and inspect action result, if it is `ObjectResult` then you can set custom json formatter.
2. Deserialization/binding. This one is tricky, you'll need custom body binder (which can be configured to use custom json formatter), custom binder provider, custom binder source and custom `IControllerModelConvention` to selectively override binding source on actions.

This should work for simple scenarios when you don't use other filters or middlewares etc.

I'm not attaching any code, because it will be a dozen of classes.